# Symfony 2.8 how to default select value in Dropdown using Propel

Tags: symfony, dropdown, selected

I have created one dropdown for employee Role. In edit mode how to select user selected role.

```
$builder->add('homePageId', \Propel\Bundle\PropelBundle\Form\Type\ModelType::class  , array( 
            'class' => 'Admin\HomePageBundle\Model\HomePage',
            'required' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false, 
            'query' => HomePageQuery::create()->orderByName(),     
            'property' => 'name',
            'preferred_choices' => array('5')            
       ));
```

I have added "preferred_choices" for select "5" number role but not working.

Please help for fixed this issue.

Comment: The selected value is the value of `homePageId` of your object.

Comment: Yes, If user click on edit any record then drop-down value must be selected.

Answer (score 1):

The selected value is the object value. I'll try to explain this way:

```
$object = new Object();
$object->setHomePageId(5);

// kinda put the 5 as selected in your form, because your object contains 5 and the form is not binded yet.
$form = $this->createForm(ObjectType, $object); 
$form->getData()->getHomePageId(); // will return 5

//kinda put the request parameter homepageId as selected in your form
$form->handleRequest($request); 
$form->getData()->getHomePageId(); // will return the user selection
```